# What's up with SharpZipLib versions?

Tags: .net, mono, compression, sharpziplib

Been having trouble lately trying to determine what's the Single Point of Truth about SharpZipLib.

**What's the real truly latest version?**

Its [github repository](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib) doesn't contain any git tag at all.

There are 3 nuget repositories:

- What looks to be the [The main one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpZipLib/), which contains the version 0.86.0.
- Another one, [named in the same way but with the suffix ".Patched"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Patched): it has several versions published ranging from 0.86.1 to 0.86.4.
- Another one, named ["ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll"](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll/), which has the version 0.85.4.369.
- Then there's the version which Mono includes in the GAC: depending on the .NET runtime version, its versions will be 2.84.0.0 (.NET 2.0) or 4.84.0.0 (.NET 4.0, or 4.x I guess).

Can anybody explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the real truly latest version?

#### The latest 'official' version would be from the github master:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.86.0.518")]
```

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/blob/master/src/AssemblyInfo.cs

**SharpZipLib : Discussion forum forzip, gzip, bzip2 and tar .NET compression library #ziplib.**
http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/12.aspx

#### The version supplied from Mono is 0.84:

```
-#if NET_2_0
+#if NET_4_0
+[assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.84.0.0")]
+#elif NET_2_0
 [assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.84.0.0")]
 #else
-// not worrying about the NET_1_0 profile for now.
-[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.84.0.0")]
+   #error "No profile"
 #endif
```

https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/c0611696133477fac99e776e58c32446b054b62d#diff-5edef1128c50390b6747e095c19c1890

Review the readme, it was pulled into the Mono repo 10 years ago to allow inline compiling with the reset of the framework...

#### The 'official' compiled/binary download is:

"All downloads are for version 0.86.0, built on 2010/05/25."
http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/

and

https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Release-History

#### The 'patched' version is from a github fork and 'nano-byte' has applied a number of date related patches, among other things:

```
+[assembly: AssemblyVersion("0.86.4")]
```

https://github.com/nano-byte/SharpZipLib

```
b4ee4aa6528bc7c1500ca269734a67bd9bac0294 Updated .gitignore
f1e878c7a3f2db26efcdfc6d8f014d6399d9d155 Incremented version number
14b432069e4232bc3b576783d1550f85c52c881f Ignore NT timestamps
6115e8df3ec296261876a87ec333457093dd29ab Incremented version number
614564b645ee54d6f75ad4702f0706917a1a75dc Improve extracting Unix and NT timestamps from ZipExtraData
eb431344f9b47a28a414f2414e4ce4dc778e82fd Back ZipEntry.DateTime with a real DateTime field instead of DosTime
b424950f686a2b1677f9a395a563878691630f66 Expose ZipEntry.HostSystem as HostSystemID enum instead of int
8723d4954cf76f756703f1a5fc762e94b66488d3 Script for making NuGet package
25c26632471da2ade32c44a87765efa427570349 Tweaked .gitignore
ea826884cf6f535a9545b98b50fb4b1d92f98850 Incremented version number
e0f530e1bfe7f4396ffa745612f9280e15254fc6 Gracefully handle missing OEMCodePage by defaulting to 850
7c842d9d04890b58f69bc8be2fb739db22c022ba Fixed XML comment error
e8e39211ee89a52835bcb1d2bda29ee094864335 Incremented version number
9abe910a6df145479bce95da7c3c351023e73181 Support long names in Tar archives ("prefix" header field as defined by ustar)
e520ccc26201c22dcc9606851889294841b2c563 Enable symlinks and hardlinks in TAR archives
87adf509f99298ec38924c66a2cfdb88a9a45732 Fixed timezone shifting
30b0ccde62ad3c39c22c153168706ea358837fbd Throw ZipException instead of generic Exception on password error
5f2bcd8258cdf11d4654b2295539430387e9e34a Tolerate 0-value (missing) local size headers.
afa64c5c76bca6c25d0fdb9039719e421b94c04a Created .nuspec file (NuGet package definition)
edb41a689fefe9ceafdfc9f9c8a0dc05a01d84bb Generate debugging symbols in Release build
a3f3e59865ee0fa089b76268dc13c29a44853a6b Added Visual Studio 2012 solution, use NuGet to download NUnit
068abd49b839c188b79cdbeb0a54f499cfa44630 Sign assembly
f08e5a9805ccc13de28be17ef25544bd4a996915 Added .gitignore file
c49a22d70a77819b1dc88309c91e99565aa9099b Create README.md
5f57a54eeca2a6c1a13265ead38249c795bc6718 Z-1684 Fixed File Timestamp being lost via ZipFile.Add with modified entry name
~~~
```

Comment: what's the nuget repo that contains the last version then?